# In Python Pandas using cumsum with groupby

Tags: pandas

I am trying to do a pandas cumsum(), where want to initialize the value to 0 every time group changes. 
Say I have below dataframe where after group by I have col2(Group) and expect col3(cumsum) while using the function

```
Value   Group   Cumsum
a   1   0
a   1   1
a   1   2
b   2   0
b   2   1
b   2   2
b   2   3
c   3   0
c   3   1
d   4   0
```

This doesnt work

```
df['Cumsum'] = df['Group'].cumsum()
```

Please advise.
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect `cumsum` to work on non numerical types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, this turned out more complicated than I imagined, due to getting the groups' keys back in. Perhaps someone else will find something shorter.

First, imports

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
```

Now a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
    'b': [0, 1, 2, 3]})
```

So now we separately do a `groupby`-`cumsum`, some itertools stuff for finding the keys, and combine both:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({
    'keys': list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([len(g) * [k] for k, g in df.b.groupby(df.a)])),
    'cumsum': df.b.groupby(df.a).cumsum()})

    cumsum  keys
0   0   a
1   1   a
2   2   b
3   4   b
```

Comment: got it  .. Thanks :)